# Python - creating a dictionary from large text file where the key matches regex pattern

Tags: regex, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

**My question:**  how do I create a dictionary from a list by assigning dictionary keys based on a regex pattern match ('^--L-[0-9]{8}'), and assigning the values by using all lines between each key.

Example excerpt from the raw file:

```
SQL> --L-93752133
SQL> --SELECT table_name, tablespace_name from dba_tables where upper(table_name) like &tablename_from_developer;
SQL> 
SQL> --L-52852243
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT log_mode FROM v$database;

      LOG_MODE
      ------------
      NOARCHIVELOG

SQL> 
SQL> archive log list
      Database log mode              No Archive Mode
      Automatic archival             Disabled
      Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
      Oldest online log sequence     3
      Current log sequence           5
SQL> 
SQL> --L-42127143
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT t.name "TSName", e.encryptionalg "Algorithm", d.file_name "File Name"
      2    FROM v$tablespace t
      3       , v$encrypted_tablespaces e
      4       , dba_data_files d
      5   WHERE t.ts# = e.ts#
      6     AND t.name = d.tablespace_name;

      no rows selected
```

**Some additional detail:**  The raw file can be large (at least 80K+ lines, but often much larger) and I need to preserve the original spacing so the output is still easy to read.  Here's how I'm reading the file in and removing "SQL>" from the beginning of each line:

```
with open(rawFile, 'r') as inFile:
    content = inFile.read()

rawList = content.splitlines()

for line in rawList:
    cleanLine = re.sub('^SQL> ', '', line)
```

Finding the dictionary keys I'm looking for is easy:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^--L-[0-9]{8}')
if pattern.search(cleanLine) is not None:
    itemID = pattern.search(cleanLine)
    print(itemID.group(0))
```

But how do I assign all lines between each key as the value belonging to the most recent key preceding them?  I've been playing around with new lists, tuples, and dictionaries but everything I do is returning garbage.  The goal is to have the data and keys linked to each other so that I can return them as needed later in my script.

I spent a while searching for a similar question, but in most other cases the source file was already in a dictionary-like format so creating the new dictionary was a less complicated problem.  Maybe a dictionary or tuple isn't the right answer, but any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should question why you would read the entire file, split the lines into a list, and then iterate over the list. This is a Python anti-pattern.

For line oriented text files, just do:

```
with open(fn) as f:
   for line in f:
       # process a line
```

It sounds, however, that you have multi-line block oriented patterns. If so, with smaller files, read the entire file into a single string and use a regex on that. Then you would use group 1 and group 2 as the key, value in your dict:

```
pat=re.compile(pattern, flags)
with open(file_name) as f:
    di={m.group(1):m.group(2) for m in pat.finditer(f.read())}
```

With a larger file, use a `mmap`:

```
import re, mmap

pat=re.compile(pattern, flags)
with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for i, m in enumerate(pat.finditer(mm)):
        # process each block accordingly...
```

As far as the regex, I am a little unclear on what you are trying to capture or not. I *think* this regex is what I am understanding you want:

```
^SQL> (--L-[0-9]{8})(.*?)(?=SQL> --L-[0-9]{8}|\Z)
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/YNj5x3/1)

In either case, running that regex with the example string yields:

```
>>> pat=re.compile(r'^SQL> (--L-[0-9]{8})\s*(.*?)\s*(?=SQL> --L-[0-9]{8}|\Z)', re.S | re.M)
>>> with open(file_name) as f:
...     di={m.group(1):m.group(2) for m in pat.finditer(f.read())}
... 

>>> di
{'--L-52852243': 'SQL> \nSQL> SELECT log_mode FROM v;\n\n      LOG_MODE\n      ------------\n      NOARCHIVELOG\n\nSQL> \nSQL> archive log list\n      Database log mode              No Archive Mode\n      Automatic archival             Disabled\n      Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST\n      Oldest online log sequence     3\n      Current log sequence           5\nSQL>',
 '--L-93752133': 'SQL> --SELECT table_name, tablespace_name from dba_tables where upper(table_name) like &tablename_from_developer;\nSQL>', 
 '--L-42127143': 'SQL> \nSQL> SELECT t.name TSName, e.encryptionalg Algorithm, d.file_name File Name\n      2    FROM v t\n      3       , v e\n      4       , dba_data_files d\n      5   WHERE t.ts# = e.ts#\n      6     AND t.name = d.tablespace_name;\n\n      no rows selected'}
```

Comment: Thanks dawg!  The reason my regex didn't include the "SQL> " portion was because after writing the file to a list I removed that pattern from the beginning of every line (in my second code snippet above).  However, leaving instances of that pattern in will also work for what I'm doing.

Comment: If the regex is capturing the right blocks, you can just replace the `"SQL> "` parts before moving on to the next one. Something like `{m.group(1):m.group(2).replace("SQL>","") for m in pat.finditer(f.read())}` or a `re.sub` if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
with open(rawFile, 'r') as inFile:
content = inFile.read()

rawList = content.splitlines()
keyed_dict = {}
in_between_lines = ""
last_key = 0
for line in rawList:
 cleanLine = re.sub('^SQL> ', '', line)
 pattern = re.compile(r'^--L-[0-9]{8}')
 if pattern.search(cleanLine) is not None:      
  itemID = pattern.search(cleanLine)
  if last_key: keyed_dict[last_key] = in_between_lines
  last_key = itemID.group(0)
  in_between_lines = ""
 else:
  in_between_lines += cleanLine
```

Comment: This looks like it's close to getting me there, but it's returning an empty dictionary when I print it.  Also, I moved "keyed_dict[last_key] = in_between_lines" so that it's on its own line within the "if last_key:" block.  Is that the correct format?

Comment: Forget it and use dawgs version ;). He is right, the whole approach is messy.